# Why is my html pop-up displaying the text of my functions instead of running them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

Okay, so I am VERY new to html and fairly new to javascript as well. I've been trying to create an html pop-up that inserts a link from a google apps script string variable and labels it "Continue". I'm not sure if my functions are even on the right track, but it almost doesn't matter, because no matter how I write them, instead of being able to execute them, the pop-up displays the entire text of all my functions. As far as I can tell, the functions never run, and even if they did, I don't want them written in my pop-up for the users to see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <scripts>
   function writeLink(link)
   {
     return link;
   }

   function getLink()
   {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(writeLink).getURL();
   }
  </scripts>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    document.write(<a href= getLink() >Continue</a>)
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried moving my scripts to inside the body, inside the head, after the body, etc. It always gives me a pop-up that displays the title, then all the text of my functions, with the word "Continue" being a blue, broken link to nothing. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious that I'm doing wrong, but no matter how much I research, I can't find it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's `<script>`, not `<scripts>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `<scripts>` instead of `<script>`

Change

```
<scripts>
   function writeLink(link)
   {
     return link;
   }

   function getLink()
   {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(writeLink).getURL();
   }
  </scripts>
```

to

```
<script>
   function writeLink(link)
   {
     return link;
   }

   function getLink()
   {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(writeLink).getURL();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I feel a little foolish for not spotting that on my own, but I really appreciate the help. Thank you. I should be able to make some progress now.